# Large encrypted database on Android app. A good practice?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to keep a 22mb large encrypted sqlite DB in the assets folder of my Android app. When the app runs, I want to copy this DB to the actual DB in /data/data/... which is also supposed to be encrypted. Then I want to sync this DB time to time with the db on my server. No doubts in implementation part, but can anyone please suggest whether it is a good practice and worth it?
Thanks.

Comment: People downvoting this question. I clearly mentioned that I have no doubts in implementation. I am just asking expert advice on whether it is a gud practice. huh

Answer (score 0):

> When the app runs, I want to copy this DB to the actual DB

This is one time initialization? It's OK, even better if you delete the seed file after initing.

> actual DB in `/data/data/`... which is also supposed to be encrypted.

AFAIK doing this means you are using at least **extra** 22 MB of RAM everytime you do a database operation. And at least 22 MB worth of disk write everytime you commit. Please do this sensibly, e.g. use batching techniques, do the disk write in a background thread, etc.

> Then I want to sync this DB time to time with the db on my server.

Depends on how you do the sync, and also the frequency. If you upload the full 22 MB **everytime**, it's not ok. If you only update what has been changed, it's ok. Give users the option to only sync when on wifi.

Comment: The seed file is going to be in assets folder of the apk which is not possible to delete after the app install. The problem is that anyone can steal that easily from the apk.

Comment: I'm not going to discuss about security and stealing, but that means its extra bloat into your apk and installation. can you try loading the seed file from your server instead, since you are going to sync anyway.

Comment: Thx @eriuzo for your suggestions :)